# Offline portable web app, Javascript. How to get a persistent database across computers?

Tags: javascript, database, portability, lokijs, persistent-data

I have an offline web app for PC with JavaScript and I am looking to add a database to it. The problem is that it requires persistent data storage across multiple computers (via USB). So I want to find a way to store this data on a USB instead of on the computer's hard drive.

I have looked into solutions such as [lokijs](http://lokijs.org/) and while lokijs does have persistent storage, it is stored inside Local Storage or IndexedDB. This means that it is stored on the computer through the browser. A way to solve this is to somehow read/write files with JavaScript or to save the database file in the same directory as the other files (for portability through USB). Is there a way to do this? To my knowledge, there isn't a way to achieve this.

Another solution would be to download a [portable version of Chrome](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) and create a .bat file to ensure that the web app will open using the portable Chrome. I think (not too sure) that the portable Chrome will keep the Local Storage/IndexedDB data in between sessions. However, this method is bulky and I would rather not rely on this.

So, is there an alternative to solve this problem? Or is there another JavaScript database out there that can locally store and retrieve a database to achieve persistent data storage across multiple computers via USB.

Thanks for reading and I'd appreciate any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want a portable, fat-client application built with web technologies. There are multiple solutions for this. I'd recommend using NodeWebKit or something similar (JavaFX also has web rendering capabilities with JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion. If you don't mind, what is your opinion about [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) vs the [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/) you mentioned?

Comment: I don't really know it, but it definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript doesn't have access to your disks - for security reasons. You can't read/write to a local drive using a web app, otherwise it would be much easier for malware to spread. That's why solutions like lokijs use in-browser storage. If you want an offline app with portable storage that can run from USB I would be looking at a rewrite using a different technology / programming language. If it needs to be cross-platform as well, Java is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion. I'll definitely look into other technologies as you and meskobalazs suggested.